# Add external library from git to my C project

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm newbie in creating CMake files
I've searched a lot but I still can't understand why I can't use any function from external library but can use #define variables from header files

I'm trying to add this library: https://github.com/pq-crystals/dilithium

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(react-native-dilithium VERSION 1.0.0)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(dilithium                              
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pq-crystals/dilithium.git
  GIT_TAG        master        
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(dilithium)

add_library(dilithium SHARED)
target_sources(dilithium PUBLIC ${dilithium_SOURCE_DIR})
set_target_properties(dilithium PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX PROPERTIES DILITHIUM_MODE 5 PROPERTIES DILITHIUM_USE_AES TRUE)

add_executable(cpp_test main.cpp)

target_include_directories(cpp_test PUBLIC 
  ${dilithium_BINARY_DIR}
  ${dilithium_SOURCE_DIR}/ref
)


target_link_libraries(cpp_test PUBLIC dilithium)
```

And I'm expecting this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <api.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Message to sign
    const char* message = "This is a message to be signed.";
    size_t message_len = strlen(message);

    // Private key (replace with your actual key)
    unsigned char private_key[pqcrystals_dilithium5aes_ref_SECRETKEYBYTES];

    // Signature buffer (allocate enough space based on parameter set)
    unsigned char signature[pqcrystals_dilithium5aes_ref_BYTES];
    size_t signature_len = sizeof(signature);

    // Call the signing function
    int result = pqcrystals_dilithium5aes_ref_signature(
        signature, &signature_len,
        (const unsigned char*)message, message_len,
        private_key
    );

    return 0;
}
```

But an error occurs when I'm trying to use pqcrystals_dilithium5aes_ref_signature

The error:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  pqcrystals_dilithium5aes_ref_signature(unsigned char*, unsigned long*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*), referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [cpp_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I'm no expert on CMake but I believe the arguments to `target_sources` should be a list of source files, not a directory `target_sources(dilithium PUBLIC ${dilithium_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: I've tried many variations, nothing helped

Comment: Well you aren't trying to do anything unusual, there must be an example you can copy.

Comment: Those examples doesn't work for this library
In api.h file declarations but no implementation, but I don't know how to include this implementations to my project.

Comment: Well maybe build from the command line instead of with CMake. If the tool isn't useful don't use it.

Comment: Header files are not libraries.  You must understand the distinction.  The header file is used by the pre-processor and the compiler.  The library is used by the linker.  Build a few programs with lower level tools to help make the distinction clear.

Comment: I understand it, for another library this approach works but not for this

Answer (score 0):

Since the library authors don't care of C++, you have to care it for them. Change

```
#include <api.h>
```

to

```
extern "C" {
#include <api.h>
}
```

Comment: Didn't help, still see the same error (